# React Native App Fails To Open On Web Port

Tags: javascript, react-native, npm, expo, react-native-web

I'm making a small project, and when I do npm start it runs fine on my ios device.

```
import { StatusBar } from 'expo-status-bar';
import { SafeAreaView, StyleSheet, Text, View } from 'react-native';
import { FlatList } from 'react-native';
import menuData from './foods.json';
import MenuItem from './Components/MenuItem';

export default function App() {

  const items = menuData.items;
  console.log(items)

  return (
    <>
    <SafeAreaView></SafeAreaView>
   <View style={styles.container}>
        <View style = {styles.topBar}>
          <Text style = {styles.title}>Menu</Text>
        </View>
        <View style = {styles.menuItems}>
          <FlatList
              data={items}
              renderItem={({item}) => 
              <MenuItem
                name = {item.name}
                desc = {item.description}
                price = {item.price}
              />}
              keyExtractor={item => item.name}
            />
        </View>
     </View>
    </>

  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: '#fff',
  },
  topBar:{
    flex:1,
    width:"100%",
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
    borderBottomWidth:1
  },
  title:{
    fontSize:30,
    fontWeight:500
  },
  menuItems:{
    flex:10,
    width:"100%",
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
  }
});
```

```
import { StyleSheet, Text, View } from 'react-native'
import React from 'react'

const MenuItem = (props) => {
  return (
    <View style = {[styles.container,props.style]}>
      <Text style = {styles.name}>{props.name}</Text>
      <Text style = {styles.desc}>{props.desc}</Text>
      <Text style = {styles.price}>{props.price}</Text>
    </View>
  )
}

export default MenuItem

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container:{
        borderRadius:10,
        backgroundColor:"#1C9CF6",
        width:370,
        height:125,
        flexDirection:"column",
        marginVertical:10,
        marginHorizontal: 20,
        borderWidth:2,
        borderColor:"#1D71F2",
    },
    name:{
        color:"white",
        fontWeight:'bold',
        fontSize:25,
        paddingHorizontal:10,
        paddingVertical:7
        
    },
    desc:{
        color:"white",
        marginHorizontal:10,
        fontSize:18,
        color:"#E3F4FE",
    },
    price:{
        color:"white",
        padding:10,
        color:"#FFFAE0",
    }
})
```

```
{
    "items": [
      {
        "name": "Cheeseburger",
        "description": "Classic beef patty with melted cheese, lettuce, and tomato",
        "price": 4.99
      },
      {
        "name": "Chicken Nuggets",
        "description": "Crispy chicken nuggets with your choice of dipping sauce",
        "price": 3.99
      },
      {
        "name": "French Fries",
        "description": "Golden and crispy potato fries",
        "price": 2.49
      },
      {
        "name": "Hot Dog",
        "description": "Grilled sausage served in a soft bun with your favorite toppings",
        "price": 3.49
      },
      {
        "name": "Milkshake",
        "description": "Creamy and refreshing milkshake in various flavors",
        "price": 3.99
      },
      {
        "name": "Chicken Sandwich",
        "description": "Tender chicken fillet with lettuce, tomato, and mayo",
        "price": 5.49
      },
      {
        "name": "Onion Rings",
        "description": "Crispy battered onion rings",
        "price": 2.99
      },
      {
        "name": "Fish and Chips",
        "description": "Crispy fish fillets with seasoned fries",
        "price": 6.99
      },
      {
        "name": "Soft Drink",
        "description": "Carbonated beverage with a choice of flavors",
        "price": 1.99
      },
      {
        "name": "Grilled Chicken Wrap",
        "description": "Grilled chicken, fresh veggies, and sauce wrapped in a tortilla",
        "price": 4.49
      },
      {
        "name": "Chicken Caesar Salad",
        "description": "Grilled chicken, romaine lettuce, croutons, and Caesar dressing",
        "price": 5.99
      },
      {
        "name": "Ice Cream Sundae",
        "description": "Delicious ice cream with toppings and a cherry on top",
        "price": 3.49
      }
    ]
  }
```

When I try to run this project on a web port, I keep getting multiple errors about things such as Invalid hook calls, and useState

[Errors:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ll9oD.png)

One of the warnings said I might have more than one copy of React in the same app. I did npm ls react and saw that I indeed had multiple. Is there a way to resolve this?

[Terminal:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BxBnZ.png)